# How does one justify $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is clear to me because of the definition of lim sup, but is there a formal way to show that?

Comment: What is your definition of limsup?

Comment: prove it by contradiction. suppose they are different and find out that you have proposed an absurd

Comment: @PedroTamaroff limsup of $x_n$ is the upper bound of $x_n$

Comment: $\lim \sup a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$, where $b_n = \sup \{a_k: k \ge n\}$. So you just need to prove that if a sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent or $\to \infty$, then $\lim x_n = \lim x_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A_n = \sup_{k \ge n} a_k$. Then by definition:

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}A_n$$

Moreover:

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty}A_{n+1}$$

So you just need to prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}A_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}A_{n+1}$. This can be done using your favorite definition of a limit.